# right use of mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

i have a table called messages that has the following columns with the following sample data

```
id  m_id  from  to   message
1   1     him   her  hellow
2   1     her   him  what sup
3   1     him   her  nothing
```

and in the session the last message was sent to "her".  How in sql can i select where from or to are not her?  I tried this code but dont know if its correct

$b would be m_id number 1

```
$result = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM mensajes WHERE m_id  = \''.$b.'\' and from,to != \''.$_session['her'].'\' ');
```

UPDATE
this code is to find the other user that is not 'her'

Comment: I think your WHERE clause is not correct.  You can't put a comma separated list into the clause.

Answer (score 0):

i solved using this query

```
$resulto = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM mensajes WHERE m_id  = \''.$b.'\' AND (from != \''.$usr.'\' OR to != \''.$usr.'\') ');
```

$usr is in this case her and $b is m_id number 1

so to take him im using:

```
if($resultad['from'] != $usr){
                 $seo .= '<input type="hidden" class="input-block-level" value="'.$resultad['from'].'" id="from" name="from">';
                }elseif($resultad['to'] != $usr){
                 $seo .= '<input type="hidden" class="input-block-level" value="'.$resultad['to'].'" id="from" name="from">';
                }
```

Comment: CAREFUL !!! You are just adding strings together for your query and WIDE-OPEN to SQL-INJECTION attacks.  Read up on it, parameterizing queries, cleaning variables posted from the web...

Comment: im usin this function to avoid it

Comment: public function limpiar($valor){
  $mysqli = $this->connection();
  $valor = $mysqli->real_escape_string($valor);
  $valor = htmlentities(strip_tags($valor), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
  return $valor;
 }